# How to Automatically update elasticsearch document?

Tags: node.js, express, elasticsearch

I'm building a backend for a basic crud app. I have a model for a title document with a field "status" which can be either "ingested, expiring and expired". The logic for an expiring document is when the expiry date - current date is less than 30 days. How do i automatically update the document store when a the expiry date has elapsed?

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic way in Elasticsearch to do that. While you could create a separate process to change that flag, it might be easier to implement your logic "expiry date - current date is less than 30 days" within your application. Then you don't have a second process, which might fail on its own etc.